# AngularJS access outside $http

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

May i know, why I can't access `$scope.auditorium` outside the `$http` method but I can access the other `$http` (e.g `$scope.exhibition`) in another `$http ($scope.auditorium)`.  Concatenating the 2 scope at the end through `$scope.combine`

Code:

```
      myApp.controller('displayCatController', ['$scope','$http', function($scope, $http){

              //Display auditoriums information
              $http({
                  method: 'GET',
                  url:'https://developers.onemap.sg/publicapi/themeapi/retrieveTheme?queryName=auditoriums&token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjMsInVzZXJfaWQiOjMsImVtYWlsIjoicHVibGljQXBpUm9sZUBzbGEuZ292LnNnIiwiZm9yZXZlciI6ZmFsc2UsImlzcyI6Imh0dHA6XC9cL29tMi5kZmUub25lbWFwLnNnXC9hcGlcL3YyXC91c2VyXC9zZXNzaW9uIiwiaWF0IjoxNTM4Mzc5ODU3LCJleHAiOjE1Mzg4MTE4NTcsIm5iZiI6MTUzODM3OTg1NywianRpIjoiMmUxZDI2NzM0YjkxYzg2N2Y4NDdkZjI1ZTVhMzQyMjgifQ.HUmGwWO7E1MJpFADcuQyVA0h6bR2Vkkp0BQrTfrEj0k'
                  }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                    $scope.auditoriums = response.data.SrchResults;
                  }, function errorCallback(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                  });



              //Display exhibitions information
              $http({
                        method: 'GET',
                  url: 'https://developers.onemap.sg/publicapi/themeapi/retrieveTheme?queryName=exhibitioncentres&token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjMsInVzZXJfaWQiOjMsImVtYWlsIjoicHVibGljQXBpUm9sZUBzbGEuZ292LnNnIiwiZm9yZXZlciI6ZmFsc2UsImlzcyI6Imh0dHA6XC9cL29tMi5kZmUub25lbWFwLnNnXC9hcGlcL3YyXC91c2VyXC9zZXNzaW9uIiwiaWF0IjoxNTM4Mzc5ODU3LCJleHAiOjE1Mzg4MTE4NTcsIm5iZiI6MTUzODM3OTg1NywianRpIjoiMmUxZDI2NzM0YjkxYzg2N2Y4NDdkZjI1ZTVhMzQyMjgifQ.HUmGwWO7E1MJpFADcuQyVA0h6bR2Vkkp0BQrTfrEj0k'
                        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                            $scope.exhibitions = response.data.SrchResults;
                    $scope.exhibitions.splice(0,1);
                        }, function errorCallback(response) {
                            console.log(response);
                        });

                    $scope.combine = $scope.exhibitions.concat($scope.auditoriums, $scope.hotels);
                    console.log($scope.combine);
      }]);
```

I am not able to access the $scope.combine, it displays nothing. But on the other hand if i were to place the $scope inside the $http, example like this :

```
      myApp.controller('displayCatController', ['$scope','$http', function($scope, $http){

              //Display auditoriums information
              $http({
                  method: 'GET',
                  url:'https://developers.onemap.sg/publicapi/themeapi/retrieveTheme?queryName=auditoriums&token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjMsInVzZXJfaWQiOjMsImVtYWlsIjoicHVibGljQXBpUm9sZUBzbGEuZ292LnNnIiwiZm9yZXZlciI6ZmFsc2UsImlzcyI6Imh0dHA6XC9cL29tMi5kZmUub25lbWFwLnNnXC9hcGlcL3YyXC91c2VyXC9zZXNzaW9uIiwiaWF0IjoxNTM4Mzc5ODU3LCJleHAiOjE1Mzg4MTE4NTcsIm5iZiI6MTUzODM3OTg1NywianRpIjoiMmUxZDI2NzM0YjkxYzg2N2Y4NDdkZjI1ZTVhMzQyMjgifQ.HUmGwWO7E1MJpFADcuQyVA0h6bR2Vkkp0BQrTfrEj0k'
                  }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                    $scope.auditoriums = response.data.SrchResults;
                  }, function errorCallback(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                  });


              //Display exhibitions information
              $http({
                        method: 'GET',
                  url: 'https://developers.onemap.sg/publicapi/themeapi/retrieveTheme?queryName=exhibitioncentres&token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjMsInVzZXJfaWQiOjMsImVtYWlsIjoicHVibGljQXBpUm9sZUBzbGEuZ292LnNnIiwiZm9yZXZlciI6ZmFsc2UsImlzcyI6Imh0dHA6XC9cL29tMi5kZmUub25lbWFwLnNnXC9hcGlcL3YyXC91c2VyXC9zZXNzaW9uIiwiaWF0IjoxNTM4Mzc5ODU3LCJleHAiOjE1Mzg4MTE4NTcsIm5iZiI6MTUzODM3OTg1NywianRpIjoiMmUxZDI2NzM0YjkxYzg2N2Y4NDdkZjI1ZTVhMzQyMjgifQ.HUmGwWO7E1MJpFADcuQyVA0h6bR2Vkkp0BQrTfrEj0k'
                        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                            $scope.exhibitions = response.data.SrchResults;
                    $scope.exhibitions.splice(0,1);
                $scope.combine = $scope.exhibitions.concat($scope.auditoriums, $scope.hotels);
                console.log($scope.combine);
                        }, function errorCallback(response) {
                            console.log(response);
                        });



      }]);
```

Please forgive me if the question is dumb, I am still rather new to AngularJS. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$http` service will run async while your declaration of `$scope.combine` will run sync and be set before the async operations are finished. Thats why the values are empty.

One option to solve this is to wait for all the async operations to finished.

Here's an example

```
myApp.controller('displayCatController', ['$scope','$http','$q', function($scope, $http, $q){

              //Display auditoriums information
              var promise1 = $http({
                  method: 'GET',
                  url:'https://developers.onemap.sg/publicapi/themeapi/retrieveTheme?queryName=auditoriums&token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjMsInVzZXJfaWQiOjMsImVtYWlsIjoicHVibGljQXBpUm9sZUBzbGEuZ292LnNnIiwiZm9yZXZlciI6ZmFsc2UsImlzcyI6Imh0dHA6XC9cL29tMi5kZmUub25lbWFwLnNnXC9hcGlcL3YyXC91c2VyXC9zZXNzaW9uIiwiaWF0IjoxNTM4Mzc5ODU3LCJleHAiOjE1Mzg4MTE4NTcsIm5iZiI6MTUzODM3OTg1NywianRpIjoiMmUxZDI2NzM0YjkxYzg2N2Y4NDdkZjI1ZTVhMzQyMjgifQ.HUmGwWO7E1MJpFADcuQyVA0h6bR2Vkkp0BQrTfrEj0k'
                  }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                    $scope.auditoriums = response.data.SrchResults;
                  }, function errorCallback(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                  });


              //Display exhibitions information
              var promise2 =$http({
                        method: 'GET',
                  url: 'https://developers.onemap.sg/publicapi/themeapi/retrieveTheme?queryName=exhibitioncentres&token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjMsInVzZXJfaWQiOjMsImVtYWlsIjoicHVibGljQXBpUm9sZUBzbGEuZ292LnNnIiwiZm9yZXZlciI6ZmFsc2UsImlzcyI6Imh0dHA6XC9cL29tMi5kZmUub25lbWFwLnNnXC9hcGlcL3YyXC91c2VyXC9zZXNzaW9uIiwiaWF0IjoxNTM4Mzc5ODU3LCJleHAiOjE1Mzg4MTE4NTcsIm5iZiI6MTUzODM3OTg1NywianRpIjoiMmUxZDI2NzM0YjkxYzg2N2Y4NDdkZjI1ZTVhMzQyMjgifQ.HUmGwWO7E1MJpFADcuQyVA0h6bR2Vkkp0BQrTfrEj0k'
                        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                            $scope.exhibitions = response.data.SrchResults;
                            $scope.exhibitions.splice(0,1);
                        }, function errorCallback(response) {
                            console.log(response);
                        });


            $q.all([promise1, promise2]).then(function(){
                $scope.combine = $scope.exhibitions.concat($scope.auditoriums, $scope.hotels);
                console.log($scope.combine);
            });

}]);
```

Comment: Alright, thanks! Is there any way i can access it outside?